# Erlang not working with internal Terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: erlang, visual-studio-code, erlang-shell

I am currently having an issue with visual studio code and erlang, I have erlang/OTP installed on my PC, and I have installed the erlang plugin for visual studio code, however I cannot run erlang from the internal terminal window. When I try to I receive this error:

```
erl : The term 'erl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ erl
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (erl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I have installed the erlang plugin*--Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Can you add a comment to the bottom of my answer describing what worked for you?  That will help other people out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [VS docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration)

> The shell [that is] used [by VS] defaults to $SHELL on Linux and OS X, and %COMSPEC% on
>   Windows. These can be overridden manually by setting
>   `terminal.integrated.shell.*` in settings.

So I would check what the value is of your `%COMSPEC%` environment variable. Or, you can override `%COMSPEC%` in the VS settings:

From the [VS docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows):

> Correctly configuring your shell on Windows is a matter of locating
>   the right executable. VS Code defaults to the %COMSPEC% environment
>   variable on Windows which typically points to the 32-bit version of
>   cmd.exe.
>
> Below are a list of common shell executables and their default
>   locations:
>
> ```
> // 64-bit cmd if available, otherwise 32-bit
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe"
> // 64-bit PowerShell if available, otherwise 32-bit
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
> // Git Bash
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
> // Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)
> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
> ```

You may also want to check if the path to erlang is in your `%PATH%` environment variable, and if not add it.  Have you ever successfully started up the erlang shell before, e.g. after you installed erlang to test that it was working?

Comment: Sorry, i had been busy, i fixed it by adding this in my settings: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\erl8.2\\bin\\erl.exe", "terminal.integrated.cwd": "A:\\Documents\\Folder\\Erlang"` I had also installed a different version of erlang, i was having issues with the version from the official website, however if downloaded from erlang solution it works, no idea why though

Answer (score 0):

Try the following guide and install erlang

https://www.rose-hulman.edu/Users/faculty/young/CS-Classes/resources/Erlang/index.html